# bookshelf.js: how to use updatePivot with a query

Tags: bookshelf.js

I am using:

```
.updatePivot({sort_order:2}, [some query goes here])
```

how can I format the query so that only the queried row in the join table is updated? I've tried:

```
.updatePivot({sort_order:2}, { where: {tagId: 117} })
```

But that still sets sort_order to 2 for all the rows in the table, not just the row where tagId=117.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for updatePivot says that the options parameter is a hash of options. so you would need to specify it as

```
.updatePivot({sort_order:2}, { query: { where: {tagId: 117} } })
```

alternately I believe you can do something like

```
.forge({tagId: 117}).related('b2m relationship').updatePivot({sort_order: 2})
```

Comment: thanks! that worked. I ended up using the attach, then detach method because I'm able to pass them arrays in order to edit multiple rows at once. There's probably a way to do that with updatePivot, but in any case this is great to know. Thanks again